# Часовой пояс Yandex map API указанной координаты или адреса

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Существует ли какой то метод, например как в Google API Map - при указывании на карте координаты или адреса - отдается часовой пояс указанного объекта. Существует ли какой то метод в этом отношении?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решений никаких не нашел, как кроме воспользоваться сторонним API - https://timezonedb.com/references/get-time-zone